# Is it possible to add swipe down when using react navigation presentation fullscreenmodal?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I use react navigation and want to show a full screen modal. Then I have seen this post:

[Modal navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/)

it works great, but can I close the modal when swiping down ? is it possible ? And when yes how I do it ?

Comment: It is already documented here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#transparent-modals

Comment: @RajendranNadar but I use nativeStack

Comment: It will auto import the supported version

Comment: I saw only iOS is supported

Comment: No it works for both android & ios

Comment: @RajendranNadar https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#gestureenabled look, they say only iOS

Comment: For stack it will work for native stack it is ios only, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#gestureenabled

Answer (score 1):

When using the Native Stack Navigator there are some limitations. One of them is that the gesture is only supported on iOS. see [Native Stack Navigator limitations](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#gestureenabled)

Answer (score 0):

what you can do, instead of using presentable: 'fullscreenmodal' use a normal screen with

```
<Stack.Screen
    name='preview/[id]'
    options={{
      animation: 'slide_from_bottom',
      headerShown: false,
      gestureDirection: 'vertical',
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do, is to wrap your stack modal content with a `GestureRecognizer` and set the proper event with a callback such as `() => props.navigation.goBack()`

```js
// navigator
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Group>
          <Stack.Screen name='list' component={ListScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name='detail' component={DetailScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Group
          screenOptions={{
            presentation: 'modal',
            animation: 'slide_from_bottom'
          }}>
          <Stack.Screen name='session' component={ModalScreen} />
        </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </View>
  );
}


// modal content
import GestureRecognizer from 'react-native-swipe-gestures';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';

function ModalScreen(props: { navigation: any }) {
  return (
    <GestureRecognizer style={{ flex: 1 }} onSwipeDown={() => props.navigation.goBack()} onUpDown={() => props.navigation.goBack()}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>This is a modal!</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => props.navigation.goBack()} title='Dismiss' />
      </View>
    </GestureRecognizer>
  );
```

Comment: This is bad UX, the animation doesn't follow the gesture. Just triggers the back after the event finishes